# While Loop taking ID value for a href

Tags: php

while loop:

```
   <tbody>
                        <?php while($row=$result->fetch_assoc()){ ?>
                            <tr> 
                                <td><?= $row['id']; ?></td>
                                <td><?= $row['fornavn']; ?></td>
                                <td><?= $row['efternavn']; ?></td>
                                <td><?= $row['mail']; ?></td>
                                <td><?= $row['kursistnummer']; ?></td>
                                <td><?= $row['unilogin']; ?></td>
                                <td>
                                <a href="read.php?id='. $row['id'] .'" class="mr-3" title="View Record" data-toggle="tooltip"><span class="fa fa-eye"></span></a>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        <?php } ?>
                    </tbody>
```

when I press the a href for each record it always results in this url
http://localhost/helloworld/read.php?id=%27.%20$row[%27id%27]%20.%27

I think its the syntax of the  ---- > `href="read.php?id='. $row['id'] .'"` but I've tried all the variations that I can find as a php beginner, it's driving me nuts!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PHP shorthand tag for echo is missing in href link.

This Code snippet should work:

```
<a href="<?= 'read.php?id='. $row['id'] ?>" class="mr-3" title="View Record" data-toggle="tooltip"><span class="fa fa-eye"></span></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

use `""` for the id attribute because you use `''` outside the `. $row['id'] .`

So like this:

```
href="read.php?id='. $row["id"] .'"
```